# Checked radio button

Tags: javascript, forms, angular

I need to know if a radio button has been selected to hide / show other options.

```
<input #r4 type="radio" name="x">
<span>Group</span>
<div class="subOption" *ngIf="r4.checked"></div>
```

div.subOption must be displayed when it has been selected.
it's correct?¿

Comment: There are some bugs related with radio boxes in ng2. Wouldn't you like to make it with check boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just create a new boolean variable in the component, that you set as true when radio button has been checked. With that boolean you then display the div. So for example:

```
isChecked: boolean = false; // our new variable

<input type="radio" name="x" (click)="isChecked = true">

<div *ngIf="isChecked">
  <!-- Your code here -->
</div>
```

**EDIT:** As to multiple radiobuttons... as mentioned in a comment, radio buttons seems at this point be kind of buggy with Angular. I have found the easiest way to deal with radio buttons seems to be using a form. So wrap your radio buttons in a form, like so:

```
  <form #radioForm="ngForm">
    <div *ngFor="let val of values">
      <input (change)="changeValue(radioForm.value)" type="radio" [value]="val.id" name="name" ngModel />{{val.name}}
    </div>
  </form>
```

whereas on radio button would look like the following in this example:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'value1'
}
```

In the form there is a `change` event, from which we pick up the chosen radio button value.

```
(change)="changeValue(radioForm.value)"
```

Then I would just play with boolean and the value chosen:

```
changeValue(val) {
  this.valueChosen = true; // shows div
  this.chosenVal = val.name; // here we have the value chosen
}
```

A plunker to play with: [**here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/TCoFxWh3VnWB0jHOkZpi?p=preview)

Comment: Your first example only works the first time. If you click again it should set isChecked to false. `isChecked = !isChecked`

Comment: Radio buttons cannot be unchecked by default, so I didn't really take that into consideration here, as it was not mentioned anywhere :)

Comment: "I need to know if a radio button has been selected to hide / show other options."

Comment: Yup, well then it has to be solved in a total different manner altogether. toggling `isChecked = !isChecked` wouldn't work anyway. If OP wants/has done programatically the option to uncheck the radio button, then at the same function the `isChecked` can be set as false then as well. But this is not mentioned anywhere, so I have not taken in consideration this. If OP is looking for another solution I would adjust my answer accordingly. But this is how I saw the question. :) Feel free to make your own answer if you feel like I have misunderstood :)

Comment: What if I had to do the same thing with several radioButtons?

Comment: @jmrosdev Updated my answer. Radio buttons are indeed a bit buggy and to use a form is a pretty good option in my opinion :)

Comment: @AJT_82 Thanks for the help. What I want is to show a div with an ngIf if I select for example the third option. This not found.
<div *ngIf="radioForm.value === 3">
    Chosen radio button has id: {{chosenVal}}
  </div>

Comment: Well if you want to have all separate divs, since you are setting the `chosenVal` you can then use it in your view like `<div *ngIf="chosenVal == 3"></div>`

Comment: @jmrosdev So if you ONLY want to check if the chosen value is 3, this is enough: http://plnkr.co/edit/KZniBS1DaAzGf1ICL54V?p=preview